# Move and resize textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a way to move the box, but also manage to change its size, but the two events are interfering (when I try to change the box's size, it activates the move event), when I click the box it becomes resizable, however it is impossible to resize as the move event overlaps. I hope my explanation has given you an idea of ​​what I need, thanks in advance for any help.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    let temp = document.querySelectorAll(".back_card");
    var index = 0, length = temp.length;
    for ( ; index < length; index++) {
       temp[index].style.display =  "none";
    }
    temp = document.querySelectorAll(".move");
    index = 0, length = temp.length;
    for ( ; index < length; index++) {
       Dragable(temp[index]);
    }

}
// Editable
function change_editable(e){
    try{
        var id_element = e.srcElement.id.toString()
    }
    catch{
        var id_element = e.path[0].id.toString()
    }
    var element = document.getElementById(id_element);
    element.classList.toggle("editable_resize");

}



//DRAG AND DROP
function addEvent(el, type, callback)
{
    if (el.addEventListener) {
       el.addEventListener(type, callback);
    } else if (el.attachEvent) {
       el.attachEvent("on" + type, callback);
    }
}



function Dragable(el)
{
    var isMove = false, 
        x = 0, y = 0, 
        xel = 0, yel = 0; 
   
    addEvent(el, "mousedown", function (e) {
        isMove = true;
            el.className += " isMoving";

            x = window.event ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
            y = window.event ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;

            xel = x - el.offsetLeft;
            yel = y - el.offsetTop;
    });
    addEvent(document, "mousemove", function (e) {
        if (isMove) {
            e.preventDefault();

            x = window.event ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
            y = window.event ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;

            el.style.left = (x - xel) + 'px';
            el.style.top  = (y - yel) + 'px';
        }
    });

    addEvent(document, "mouseup", function () {
        el.className = String(el.className).replace(/(^|\s)isMoving(\s|$)/g, " ");
        isMove = false;
    });
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style type="text/css">

/*TEXTAREA*/ 
textarea{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.150);
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
}


.editable_resize{
    resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

    /* MOVE*/
    .move{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1000;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #fc0;
    }

.isMoving {
   z-index: 1001 !important;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div
            id="text_box1"
            class="move">
              <textarea 
          id="text_area1" 
          style="width:100%; height: 100%;" 
          onclick="change_editable(event)"> INSERT YOUR TEXT</textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

You can just check if the mouse pointer is in range of resize by checking if the mouse pointer is at bottom right corner.

With this solution you can implement resizing in all direction if you want.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let temp = document.querySelectorAll(".back_card");
  var index = 0,
    length = temp.length;
  for (; index < length; index++) {
    temp[index].style.display = "none";
  }
  temp = document.querySelectorAll(".move");
  index = 0, length = temp.length;
  for (; index < length; index++) {
    Dragable(temp[index]);
  }

}
// Editable
function change_editable(e) {
  try {
    var id_element = e.srcElement.id.toString()
  } catch {
    var id_element = e.path[0].id.toString()
  }
  var element = document.getElementById(id_element);
  element.classList.toggle("editable_resize");

}



//DRAG AND DROP
function addEvent(el, type, callback) {
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener(type, callback);
  } else if (el.attachEvent) {
    el.attachEvent("on" + type, callback);
  }
}

function Dragable(el) {
  var isMove = false,
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    xel = 0,
    yel = 0;

  addEvent(el, "mousedown", e => {
    const rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const _x = e.clientX - rect.left;
    const _y = e.clientY - rect.top;
    
    // check if the mouse pointer is in is-resizing range
    if(rect.width - _x <= 18 && rect.height - _y <= 18) return;
    
    isMove = true;
    el.className += " isMoving";

    x = window.event ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
    y = window.event ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;

    xel = x - el.offsetLeft;
    yel = y - el.offsetTop;
  });

  addEvent(document, "mousemove", function(e) {
    if (isMove) {
      e.preventDefault();

      x = window.event ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
      y = window.event ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;

      el.style.left = (x - xel) + 'px';
      el.style.top = (y - yel) + 'px';
    }
  });

  addEvent(document, "mouseup", function() {
    el.className = String(el.className).replace(/(^|\s)isMoving(\s|$)/g, " ");
    isMove = false;
  });
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style type="text/css">
    /*TEXTAREA*/
    
    textarea {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.150);
      resize: none;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #fc0;
    }
    
    .editable_resize {
      resize: both;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    /* MOVE*/
    
    .move {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1000;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      
    }
    
    .isMoving {
      z-index: 1001 !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="text_box1" class="move">
    <textarea id="text_area1" style="width:100%; height: 100%;" onclick="change_editable(event)"> INSERT YOUR TEXT</textarea>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I had already found a solution, but in my view yours surpasses the one I found, thank you very much for your answer

Comment: @RafaelMR anytime man <3